# RXJS - return observable value when doing a map

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have an array of `inputIds` where I am doing a map that returns a name and value object. Inside the map, I am calling `this.inputService.getInputFieldObject` which returns an `Observable<InputValue>`. How do I return the value of the subscription instead of returning an array of subscription values? So I could have attributes returned as an array with only name and value.

```
const attributes = inputIds.map((attributeName: string) => {
  // this.inputService.getInputFieldObject returns Observable<InputValue>

  const inputSubscription = this.inputService.getInputFieldObject(attributeName).subscribe((val) => val.value)

  return {
    name: attributeName,
    value: inputSubscription, // is there a getValue method to get value of subscription?
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap it in a [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) and subscribe to that, like this:

```
forkJoin(
   inputIds.map((attributeName: string) => 
       this.inputService.getInputFieldObject(attributeName).pipe(
           map((inputValue: InputValue) => { 
               return { 
                   name: attributeName,
                   value: inputValue
               };
           })
       )
).subscribe(
    (result: { name: string, value: InputValue }[]) => {
        // do what you need to do with the result
    },
    (error) => {
        // add code here if you need to handle failure on any of the calls 
        // to this.inputService.getInputFieldObject(), or any processing thereafter.
    }
);
```

To explain what the code is doing:

**1.** This calls `inputService.getInputFieldObject()` for each `attributeName` in `inputIds`. This returns an array of `Observables<InputValue>`

```
inputIds.map((attributeName: string) => this.inputService.getInputFieldObject(attributeName))
```

**2.** We pipe each call to `this.inputService.getInputFieldObject()` to a map to return both the attributeName and inputValue. So, instead, we are now returning an array of `Observables<{ name: attributeName, value: inputValue }>`

```
this.inputService.getInputFieldObject(attributeName).pipe(
    map((inputValue: InputValue) => { 
        return { 
            name: attributeName,
            value: inputValue
        };
    })
)
```

**3.** Then we wrap ALL of these with a [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) and then subscribing to that. `forkJoin` can receive an array of Observables and waits for **all** of them to **complete**. By doing so, we are waiting for all the observables to return their (final) emitted values before we process the result. So the value you receive in the `subscribe()` would be an array of `{ name: string, value: InputValue }`:

```
forkJoin(
    ....
).subscribe((result: { name: string, value: InputValue }[]) => {
  // do what you need to do with the result
})
```

**Important Note:**

If any of the calls to `inputService.getInputFieldObject()` fails, the error callback on your `subcribe()` will be triggered, instead of the success callback.